# Greedy construction and dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

For a project I am working on, I decided to adopt the MVVM pattern.

My viewmodel needs to launch many different dialogs, which do more than just simply show OK or Cancel buttons. Most dialogs have a listview to select an item from.

To keep the viewmodel "lookless" I am injecting the different dialogs as interfaces in the viewmodel constructor.

```
public ContractsData(IWindow ProjectSelector, IWindow ContractSelector, IWindow DebtorSelector)
    {
        //.....
        //.....
        m_ProjectSelector = ProjectSelector;
        m_ContractSelector = ContractSelector;
        m_DebtorSelector = DebtorSelector;
    }
```

With IWindow being:

```
public interface IWindow
{
    void Close();
    bool? ShowDialog();
    void SetOwner(object window);
    bool? DialogResult { get; set; }
    object DataContext { get; set; }
}
```

However nice it is to be able to separate data from views from a testing point of view, all possibly needed dialog windows have to be present and fully constructed upon construction of the viewmodel, which goes against one of my principles, that of "lazy initialisation": only construct an object when you need it. 
As my viewmodel grows, it will possibly need a whole bunch of dialogs, which will all be created up front and  sleeping in memory until needed, which very well may never be.

I was thinking of replacing the actual dialogs with lightweight "Factory" objects, that construct the dialogs on request from the view, but I am looking for a better solution to solve the memory issues with dependency injection.

Comment: Are these complex our simple dialogs? So long as any mergedictionaries are being resolved without errors, and the dialogs are not tripping any binding errors, the dialogs should load up quite quickly even using lazy VM construction. I'm not sure which mvvm you're using, so I don't know how you're hydrating the view-to-viewmodel relationship, so that might color my observations a little.

Comment: The dialogs are similar in that the Listview's ItemsSource and SelectedItem properties are shared in the viewmodel. Also they share OnOK and OnCancel commands. Other than that, they are very different. My viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and serves as datacontext for the main window as well as the dialogs. I am not sure though if sharing ItemsSource properties between different listviews is recommended.

Comment: Lazy constructing them would be a pretty good idea, if you find yourself facing performance issues at the time of construction - ctors that do too much is a classic gotcha in DI. Deferring the cost by lazy'ing up whatever you can, helps in varying degrees on this front. Not sure about how much memory you will conserve. I generally prefer empirical metrics, which means pulling out my ants profiler to get a clear idea. Tracking memory consumption is a different story with each new project, from my perspective.

Comment: This isn't MVVM, even though you're abstracting the UI away, so whatever you want to do, go for it.  This pattern is more like MVC where your ViewModel is actually the Controller.  But whatever gets it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a dependency injection container, most of them will be having a feature to inject [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So instead of `IWindow` you could take dependency on `Lazy<IWindow>`. Without any special registrations they are clever to inject [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for you.

If you're using poor man's injection, you could manually construct `Lazy<IWindow>` and inject it. Otherwise [Abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is another good option.

Comment: I didn't know about the Lazy<T> template. I will give this a try.

Comment: Dependency injecting a Func<T> is another way that I've seen.

Comment: @code4life That's effectively equal to injecting an abstract factory which I already mentioned in my answer. And yes we can use `Func<T>` also. Many DI containers does that for free.